# How to exclude source code from coverage statistics in Clang12 source based coverage

Tags: clang, llvm, code-coverage, clang++

I am using clang12 compiler to instrument and get coverage statistics for my project.
However I want to exclude logging lines from my coverage statistics. Depending on the verbose mode the logs are either printed or not printed. The coverage on the Logging macro is not a useful information.

I tried using **// LCOV_EXCL_START** and **// LCOV_EXCL_STOP** but that does not seem to work.
Appreciate any direction on this.